# Почему не работает или обновляется cookie?

Tags: javascript, cookie

Суть скрипта:
Открыть модальное окно, один раз при открытии сайта, каждые 2 дня, с задержкой перед открытием 5 сек.

Кука добавляется, окно показывается, но только один раз. Через два дня не появляется. Может потому-что она обновляется каждый раз когда заходишь на сайт? Что не так в коде?

```
if (!$.cookie('was')) {
 setTimeout(function() {
  $('#boxUserFirstInfo').arcticmodal({
   closeOnOverlayClick: false,
   closeOnEsc: true,
  });
 }, 5000);
 $.cookie('was', true, {
 expires: 2,
  path: '/'
 });
};
```

Comment: [`;expires`= _date-in-GMTString-format_ If not specified it will expire at the end of session.](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie#new-cookie_expires)

Comment: `2` - Это не дата в формате GMT

Comment: Это время хранения куки в днях

Comment: о, точно, добавь в вопрос ссылку на `$.cookie`